# Structure for SQL date tracking - 32 weeks of colums, or rows?

Tags: sql

I'm tracking repeat purchases by new customers for 32 weeks after their initial purchase, with the end goal being a Tableau dash.

If I have a column in my table for week number, meaning 32 rows per new customer, working with queries and math and Tableau is simple. But is this the best/proper way to do this? Or is it better/more structurally sound to have 32 *columns* for week number, leaving me with *one row* for the customer record?

Storage is not a concern, but the correct method definitely is. Can anyone weigh in? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: *to have 32 columns* - No! Don't do that.

Comment: What @stu said!

Comment: Actually - don't have 32 rows either. Have 1 row per purchase - capture the date and calculate the "week number" since initial purchase. What if they purchase twice in the same week

Comment: Just store the data per customer with a timestamp as appropriate; the week number is something you can later extract or use a calculated column for and group by for reporting.

Comment: @CHill60 The data is for quantity of purchases per week by customer. Imagine it effectively only has 3 columns: Customer, Number of purchases, Week number (or 32 columns of Number of purchases).

Comment: To track information correctly you should first capture it. Both Stu and I are suggesting that you capture each purchase for each customer and timestamp it. What you are then referring to is analysing that data to give the number of purchases per week - it is simple with Group By.
By doing it properly you give yourself more options later - don't throw away data for the sake of it - you've already stated that storage is not an issue.